# Integral calculations with exponentials ($\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{ax^2+bx+c-1}$)

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, definite-integrals, exponential-function, gaussian

I have a **probability distribution function** (pdf) $f(x)$ wich has the following form:

$$f(x)=e^{ax^2+bx+c-1}$$

Let's assume that the pdf has a **mean value** $\mu$ and a **variance value** $\sigma^2$.

I want to prove that this pdf is the Gaussian function. So, I want to show that:

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}exp\left \{\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right \}$$

I consider finding the parameters $a$, $b$ and $c$ by making use of the following equations:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)=1$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}xf(x)=\mu$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x^2f(x)=\sigma^2 + \mu^2$$

However, I find diffuculty on calculating these integrals since I am not very familiar with such exponential integrations that have a polynomial exponent with a 2nd or higher degree.

For instance, how do I have to approach the first one ($\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)=1$)? Do I have to make use of the Gaussian integral somehow? ($\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}=\sqrt{\pi}$). It seems to me that the integral is divergent.

For the other two equations do I have to make use of integration by parts and if so how do I have to approach it?

Any help is appreciated!Thanks in advance!

Comment: The third equation should be $\int_{\mathbb{R}} x^2 f(x)dx=\sigma^2+\mu^2$.

Comment: @aziiri Yeah you're right since I don't have a zero mean value $\mu$. I just corrected that. Thanks for mentioning! If you could provide an answer it would be really helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that $a<0$ or else the integral would diverge. Instead of treating the three equations separately, we can combine them to get some easier integrals, Let

$$A=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\ dx,\quad  B= \int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x)\ dx,\quad C=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 f(x)\ dx$$

Notice that $2a B+b A=0$ because

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty (2ax+b)e^{a x^2+bx +c-1}\ dx = \bigg [e^{a x^2+bx +c-1}\bigg]_{-\infty}^{\infty}=0$$

Which gives you the necessary condition $2a\mu+b=0$ or $a=\frac{-b}{2\mu}$ (This means that $b>0$). Now we can write $f$ as

$$f(x)= \exp\left(-\frac{b}{2\mu}\left(x^2-2\mu x+\mu^2\right)+c-1+\frac{b\mu}{2}\right)= d \exp\left(-\frac{b}{2\mu}\left(x-\mu\right)^2\right)$$

(I have replaced $e^{c-1+\frac{b\mu}{2}}$ by d). You can use $A$ to find that $d= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \sqrt{\frac{b}{\mu}}$. Now the last piece of the puzzle is $b$. Notice that

$$\sigma^2 =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  d(x^2-\mu x) \exp\left(-\frac{b}{2\mu}\left(x-\mu\right)^2\right)\ dx = d \left(\frac{\mu}{b}\right)^{3/2} 
\sqrt{2\pi}=\frac{\mu}{b}$$

Now, $b=\frac{\mu}{\sigma^2}$, and your desired resuult follows immediately from this.

Comment: Thank you very much for the analytic end-to-end explanation. I have been following your answer until the definition of constant $d$. Everything makes pretty much sense until that point. However, I am a bit confused on how you calculated $d$ using $A$ and came up with the fact that $d= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \sqrt{\frac{b}{\mu}}$.

Comment: Moreover, I am also a bit confused on the last step where we want to calculate $b$. I get that:
$$\sigma^2 =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  d(x^2-\mu x) \exp\left(-\frac{b}{2\mu}\left(x-\mu\right)^2\right)\ dx$$

(You used the definiton of mean value to express $\mu$ and subtracted two integrals).

However, why is the above expression equal to $$d \left(\frac{\mu}{b}\right)^{3/2} 
\sqrt{2\pi}$$ I must be missing something.

Comment: Write the integral as

$$d \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  x(x-\mu ) \exp\left(-\frac{b}{2\mu}\left(x-\mu\right)^2\right)\ dx$$

Use integration by parts and then u_subs to compute this integral.

Comment: What do you mean by u_subs?

Comment: U substitutions.

Comment: Ok I got it! However, how did u calculate constant $d$? Did you calculate the integral $A$ by first making a u substitution as follows:
$$A = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}d\cdot e^{\frac{-b}{2\mu}(x-\mu)^2}dx=d\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{\frac{-b}{2\mu}u^2}du$$
and then use the Gaussian Integral ?? : 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-ax^2}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}$$

Comment: Yes, You know that $A=1$, then you just need to solve a linear equation for $d$.

Comment: Ok I see! Thanks again for your extensive and comprehensible solution. I wouldn't have thought to approach the problem that way, so It really helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c+1=\left(\sqrt{a}x+\frac{b}{2\sqrt{a}}\right)^2+\left(c+1-\frac{b^2}{4a}\right)$$
now if we have:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{f(x)}dx$$
we can use the substitution:
$$u=\sqrt{a}x+\frac{b}{2\sqrt{a}}\Rightarrow du=\sqrt{a}dx\Rightarrow dx=\frac{du}{\sqrt{a}}$$ and our integral becomes:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}e^{u^2+(c+1-b^2/4a)}du=\frac{\exp\left(c+1-\frac{b^2}{4a}\right)}{\sqrt{a}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{u^2}du$$
now this last integral is definately divergent and is easy to show, I have however laid it out like this incase you meant for the polynomial to be negative which would lead you to the gaussian integral :)

Comment: $a$ could be negative, which would yield a convergent integral.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!However, there are no constraints for the parameters a,b and c. The goal is to end up with the Gaussian function, so I have to find a unique solution for the 3×3 system, which means the integral has to be convergent.

Comment: @MJ13 well for the integral to be convergent $a<0$